# In sidekiq, what does the colon before variable mean?

Tags: yaml, sidekiq

I ran into a sidekiq configuration YAML file :

```
---
:concurrency: 25
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - ["critical", 2]
  - high
  - low
```

and there are colons before variables. What do they mean?

Comment: The colon in front of the key makes that key a **symbol** and not a **string**

Comment: In YAML there are no variables, and a plain scalar starting with a colon is nothing special (assuming there is no space after the colon). sidekiq assigns  meaning that way, which is a poor way of doing things given that YAML has tags to make such things explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the above file in console, you're output will look something like this

For keys with colon prefixed

`:concurrency: 25` will look like `:concurrency => 25`

For keys without colon prefixed

`staging:` will look like `"staging"`

> Also, converting to symbol is very specific to Ruby only as the
>   interpreter takes care of it.